# Keep a maximum of 5 rows in a table (Room/Sqlite)

Tags: sqlite, android-room

I want to store the last 5 searches a user performed in a SQLite table using `Room`. How can I always delete the oldest entry when there are more than 5 entries?

- I don't want to add a date column and sort by date, as for privacy reasons I don't want to store the time when a user performed the search
- I don't want to use an autoincrement id column, as it's theoretically limited at some given maximum that the ID can be

Could I maybe use the `rowid`? So checking if the number of entries in the table is larger than 5, then sort by `rowid` ascending and delete the first entry? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use an autoincrement id column, as it's theoretically
> limited at some given maximum that the ID can be

On that logic one shouldn't use autoincrement values in database at all. I doubt you really have such a data that `Long` with its maximum value (9223372036854775807) wouldn't be enough or could be achieved.

Well, as one more alternative - you can use next schema if there is 5 rows in your table and you have int `id` field for example:

1. Delete row with minimal id (I guess it would be `0`)
2. Update all the rows with one query, decreasing their `id` by 1.

```
@Query("update search_table set id = id - 1")
fun reorderData()
```

3. insert new row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented a similar case.

In my use-case I had a `timestamp` field in my table. Which I used to order the search suggestions. You can apply the same logic using another field, such as an auto-incrementing Primary field.

So, in my `Dao`, I created a `@Transaction` and in it, after insertion I remove the expired rows.

```
abstract class SearchSuggestionsDao {
    @Transaction
    open fun addSearchSuggestionWithLimit(
        searchSuggestion: SearchSuggestion,
        maxRecordsToKeep: Int = MAX_SUGGESTIONS_RECORDS_TO_KEEP,
    ) {
        addSearchSuggestion(searchSuggestion)
        maintainMaxRecordsOf(maxRecordsToKeep)
    }

    fun maintainMaxRecordsOf(
        maxRecordsToKeep: Int,
    ) {
        val allSuggestions = searchSuggestionsSortedByTimeStampDescending()

        if (allSuggestions.size > maxRecordsToKeep) {
            val expiredSuggestions = allSuggestions.subList(maxRecordsToKeep, allSuggestions.size)
            deleteSearchSuggestions(expiredSuggestions)
        }
    }

    @Delete
    abstract fun deleteSearchSuggestions(
        searchSuggestions: List<SearchSuggestion>,
    )

    @Query("SELECT * FROM search_suggestions ORDER BY timeStamp DESC")
    abstract fun searchSuggestionsSortedByTimeStampDescending(): List<SearchSuggestion>
}
```